# Jquery serialize no obtiene inputs dentro de div

Tags: jquery, ajax

Tengo el código que incluyo al pie y no entiendo por qué `var formdata = $("#AgregarVarios").serialize();`  no incluye los campos dentro del `<div id="avis" class="avis">` pero sí el que está fuera de ese DIV.

```js
var formdata = $("#AgregarVarios").serialize();     

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "destino.php",
            data: formdata,
                  async: true,
            beforesend: function(data){
            $('.avis').html("<p align='center'><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' /><div class='help-block'>Obteniendo datos...</div></p>") 
            },
            success: function(data){
            $('.avis').html(data) 
            },
            error: function(data){
            $('.avis').html(data) 
            }
        });
```

```html
<form class="form-inline" id="AgregarVarios" method="post" name="fo3">
<input type="text" name="nombre" value="xxxx">
<div id="avis" class="avis">
<input type="text" name="codigoescaneado[]" value="30097177294">
<input type="text" name="codigoescaneado[]" value="30097201783">
<input type="text" name="codigoescaneado[]" value="30097355150">
</div>
    
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de probar tu ejemplo y si trae toda la información

esto es lo que me imprime en pantalla
`nombre=xxxx&codigoescaneado%5B%5D=30097177294&codigoescaneado%5B%5D=30097201783&codigoescaneado%5B%5D=30097355150`

Observa que `codigoescaneado[]` lo está devolviendo como `codigoescaneado%5B%5D` esto es porque el método `serialize()` te devuelve un `string` en `codigo porciento`.

Intenta cambiando el nombre de los últimos 3 `input` o en tu `PHP` usa el método `urldecode()` al momento de obtener `data`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Veré nuevamente qué sucede.

Comment: Encontré el problema.
Sucedía que todo estaba dentro de un DIV que tenía style display:none y cuando el style cambiaba a display:block no funcionaba. 
Tuve que iniciar el documento con ese div con display:block para que funcione.